# Build Django WebService from existing WSDL

Tags: python, django, web-services, wsdl

I need to rewrite an existing WebService as part of a Django application, the goal is to integrate the Django application to a legacy system that can just call this particular WebService.

So I do have a very complex WSDL file with several methods and a huge data structure. Is there any way to generate a stub for an application in Django using that WSDL file, or do I have to create all the necessary data structures and method signatures myself?

Answer (score 3):

Check out [Zeep](http://docs.python-zeep.org/en/master/)

Zeep inspects the WSDL document and generates the corresponding code to use the services and types in the document.

**views.py (Server)**

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views import View
from zeep import Client

class MyConvertKilometer2MilesView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        # <view logic>
        client = Client('http://www.webservicex.net/ConvertSpeed.asmx?WSDL')
        result = client.service.ConvertSpeed(
            100, 'kilometersPerhour', 'milesPerhour')
        return HttpResponse('result')
```

If you are not sure how fast you get returns (due to the nature of SOAP), use a

- [dango-channels tasks](https://github.com/furious-luke/django-cq) or
- [celery tasks](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/calling.html)

**Command Line tests with Zeep**

If you like to test something inbetween, you may us the command line interface of Zeep to make this easy.

```
python -m zeep http://www.soapclient.com/xml/soapresponder.wsdl
```

The "Client" class from the "zeep" library is used to create a client object that will connect to the specified WSDL endpoint, "http://www.webservicex.net/ConvertSpeed.asmx?WSDL". This client object is then used to call the "ConvertSpeed" method of the web service, passing in the parameters "100", "kilometersPerhour", and "milesPerhour".

**views.py (Client)**

A Django example that generates a client view would be:

```
# views.py (Client)

from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views import View
from zeep import Client

class MyConvertKilometer2MilesView(View):
    def get(self, request, speed):
        client = Client('http://www.webservicex.net/ConvertSpeed.asmx?WSDL')
        result = client.service.ConvertSpeed(speed, 'kilometersPerhour', 'milesPerhour')
        return HttpResponse(result)
```

You also need to update the routing configuration in urls.py file to include this parameter in the url path.

```
# urls.py

from django.urls import path
from .views import MyConvertKilometer2MilesView

urlpatterns = [
    path('convert/<int:speed>/', MyConvertKilometer2MilesView.as_view()),
]
```

Comment: From the question I understand that the question is asking on how to generate a server, and the answer is speaking about how to generate a client.

Comment: @txomon I updated it and included the server part.

Comment: the current solution is just wrapping a client behind a view. A WS SOAP server would be the expectation, not a WS SOAP client used by a REST server.